# Replace only the last occurrence of <br /> in a string

Tags: regex, preg-replace, replace

This is an example content (in spanish)

`Definición<br />
Elementos del fuego<br />
Clases de fuego, ¿Cómo evitar que comiencen las clases de fuego?<br />
Métodos de extinción<br />
Tipos de extintores portátiles<br />
Forma de usar los extintores portátiles<br />
Protección pasiva para el control de incendios, tipos de componentes.<br />
Procedimientos preventivos en caso de incendios en minería<br />`

I want to remove the last `<br />` occurrence using php `preg_replace()`.

I have tried with

```
preg_replace('/<br \/>$/', '<br class="last" />', $content);
```

but does not woks. The compiler trows an error.

What can I do please?

Comment: is the `<br />` always on the end of the string?

Comment: *"The compiler trows an error."* What error? It works fine here: http://codepad.org/hCcF3iYW

Comment: An alternative to what you're doing: You could use CSS `br:last-of-type` to style the item, rather than adding a class to it.

Comment: Now I'm not getting the Warning but does not work neither. Not replace the last one. Perhaps is because in the code after every <br /> there is a new line and it's no in a single line as in the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regex pattern with negative lookahead `(?!...)`, such as

```
<br \/>(?!.*<br \/>)
```

Comment: This means "match `<br />`, as long as you can't find another `<br />` ahead." This will allow the regex to work even if there are spaces or whatnot coming after your `<br />`

Comment: Thanks but this replace all the <br /> not only the last. :( Perhaps I'm missing something

Comment: correct, i believe this is what the OP wants. notice the wording, `"the last <br /> occurrence"`

Comment: @NullUserException, you've explained *why* it works only when there is no line break after any of the `<br />`s. Chances are the OP's input really contains a `\r` and/or `\n`, even more so because he mentions it replaces more than desired. See: http://ideone.com/yfuUv (also @Ωmega, btw).

Comment: @Ωmega, and how did you come to that conclusion? Didn't you notice *all* got down-voted? At least your answer was downvoted for a reason: it doesn't work in all cases (which I explained in a comment and in my answer) :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that when using regex with look ahead:

```
$text = "foo bar <br /> \nbaz <br /> <br /> mu";

echo preg_replace('/<br \/>(?!.*<br \/>)/', '<br class="last" />', $text) . "\n";
```

will cause two `<br />` to be replaced since the `.` (dot) meta char does not match line breaks. So the above will print:

```
foo bar <br class="last" /> 
baz <br /> <br class="last" /> mu
```

You might also want to account for "<BR>" or "<br   />" (more than one space).

```
echo preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>(?!.*<br\s*/?>)#is', '<br class="last" />', $text) . "\n";
```

*(the `i` makes the pattern case-insensitive, and the `s` lets `.` match line break chars as well)*

which will print:

```
foo bar <br /> 
baz <br /> <br class="last" /> mu
```

If you're sure the *needles* will always look like `<br />`, then a couple of str-operations would also do the trick:

```
$text = "foo bar <br /> \nbaz <br /> <br /> mu";
$needle = "<br />";
$index = strrpos($text, $needle);

if($index) {
  echo substr_replace($text, '<br class="last" />', $index, strlen($needle)) . "\n";
}
```